# Which way to return an int is more proper, i.e Is variable needed

Tags: c#

I'm still learning C#, having migrated over from VB.Net and I've always wondered, in certain cases, why do I need a variable.

Given this snippet;

```
public int GetWaitTime(bool webProtocolError, int currentWait)
    {
       if (!webProtocolError)
        {
            if (currentWait < 16000)
                return currentWait + 250;
        }

        if (currentWait < 10000)
        {
            return 10000;
        }
        if (currentWait < 240000 && currentWait >=10000)
        {
            return currentWait*2;
        }
        return 240000;
    }
```

versus this snippet

```
public int GetWaitTime(bool webProtocolError, int currentWait)
    {
       var newWait = currentWait;
       if (!webProtocolError)
        {
            if (currentWait < 16000)
                newWait = currentWait + 250;
                return newWait;
        }
        if (currentWait < 10000)
        {
            newWait =10000;
            return newWait;
        }
        if (currentWait < 240000 && currentWait >=10000)
        {
            newWait = currentWait*2;
            return newWait;
        }
        return 240000;
  }
```

Is there any real difference? Visual studio sees all as ints so I dont see any type issue. I'd love to hear feedback on which is the most proper way in C# from the experts.

Comment: Why do you need `newWait` in second snippet at all?

Comment: that's the whole point of the question!

Comment: What do you mean by  'proper way' ?

Comment: In the old days it was harder to see the return values of methods, so sometimes people put the return value into a variable. Nowadays you can set a breakpoint on the closing brace of the method and see the return value there, so that particular use of a local variable went away.

Comment: I think the optimizer would just optimize your variable away anyway. But your statement "why I need a variable in certain cases" is unclear. What cases are those?

Comment: By the way, you can remove `&& currentWait >=10000` from `if (currentWait < 240000 && currentWait >=10000)` because the previous `if` would have returned if that condition was true, so there's no need to retest it.

Comment: Is the question how value type should be returned? It looks like **you think** you are returning *reference* to local variable in second snippet.

Comment: @Mike Wise..in cases like the snippet I posted, do I need to waste the code lines for having a variable when its clear its an int and returning an int.

Comment: No, the function will return an int in anycase. And I believe the optimizer will notice your variable is not needed, and not even allocate space for it on the stack anyway (I know some compiler would anyway, not sure about the C# one).

Comment: @Mike Wise .. so then the first version is the better one

Comment: Your code is not identical. You miss a pair of curly bracket in `if (currentWait < 16000)`.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen ..they arent necessary there

Comment: @mike-wise I checked the MSIL output for the two code snippets (Release build) and it looks like for snippet 2 a local variable for newWait is actually created. (  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 newWait)) Also, snippet 2 executes more CPU cycles (IL operations) , about 40%-45% more.

Comment: Many programmers will do code like this for debugging purposes. It makes it easy to set a breakpoint at the return statement, and see in the variable what will actually be returned.

Comment: There are also tools to help with debugging, like [OzCode](http://oz-code.com/) where you can see the values of subexpressions even without variables.

Comment: @dinotom If you omit the curly brackets, the result might be different. Here's a [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MRIQP.png) of the test. The parameter values of the method is false and 20000. The first result (without declaring a new variable) is 40000. The second result is 20000.

Comment: Please note that the omission of those curly braces does actually make the code do something else. You haven't just introduced an extra variable, the code also behaves different. If the currentWait is less than 16000 in the first example, you will end up at the final return which will return 24000, but in the second example you will always return newWait.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen..noted...Ill test as well as I couldn't see your second snippet

Comment: It's your second method. I just changed the name into GetWaitTime2.

Comment: @dinotom Here's the [test](http://ideone.com/JJmLIf) in Ideone. You can see the results are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q:** Is there a difference?

**A:** Yes, you've declared an extra variable in the second example.

---

**Q:** Will this make a difference in the final compiled code?

**A:** It may or it may not. It may for instance be that the compiler decides to create a temporary unnamed variable in the first code snippet anyway, which would make the two actually compile to nearly identical IL.

---

**Q:** Will this actually make a difference in terms of runtime, results, accuracy, etc.?

**A:** Not in the slightest.

---

*Opinion ahead*

**Q:** Which one should I use as a template for "how to do thing"?

**A:** For this kind of code, the first. If you have problems reading the code, like big expressions with lots of moving parts and subexpressions, feel free to create new variables with good names that document what those subexpressions are, do, and calculate, but don't just introduce variables because you can.

Comment: Plus the bug in the second code, caused by missing curly braces around the second `if` body.

Comment: I feel that the missing curly braces are somewhat orthogonal to the actual question here. They're certainly something that should be fixed, but I don't see this as "I rewrote the code to do something else in addition to having an extra variable", though I might obviously be wrong on that count.

Comment: I thought it was worth mentioning, since it is a difference in the code and an error source caused by adding a local variable to a oneliner if not careful.

Comment: I would be glad to see an example where variable make any sensable difference to result. As I dont see a case when a developer should really care about it. (unless he is doning some very low level optimisation for fun, as gain here so small)

Comment: One place where I know that the introduction of a variable might make a difference is the one place where it shouldn't matter anyway, and that is if you introduce variables to hold floating point subexpression values. The CPU may work with higher precision than the variables can store, which means that as long as the expression can be evaluated fully on the cpu and not be stored into a truncated variable, then it may give a slightly different result than with a variable. And then, if you write code that depends on this kind of precision, you're doing it wrong anyway.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen.. there is no need for the curly braces, and the editor doesnt see them as necessary either. This statement is perfectly acceptle in C# is it not? if (!webProtocolError && currentWait < 16000) return currentWait + 250;

Comment: @dinotom I think you really should learn when you can omit the curly braces.

Comment: The code is different, yes, it is legal C# but the two code pieces doesn't do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference, the main thing here is style of code. It should be easy to follow and maintain.

Few recomendations:

1. Try avoid nested if statements (if inside if). Sometimes it is not as easy as it sounds, but visual studio has got [complexity measures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb385914.aspx) to help you.

   ```
   if (!webProtocolError)
   {
       if (currentWait < 16000)
          return currentWait + 250;
   }

   if (!webProtocolError && currentWait < 16000)
   {
       return currentWait + 250;
   }
   ```
2. Try avoid magic numbers (if appropriate). Use constants described in your class.

   ```
   if (currentWait < 10000)
   {
       newWait =10000;
       return newWait;
   }

   private const int MinimumWait= 10000;
   if (currentWait < MinimumWait)
   {
       return MinimumWait;
   }
   ```
3. If you have virable to store result of your function, callculate it inside body and use it to return in the end of the method.

   ```
   public int GetWaitTime(bool webProtocolError, int currentWait)
   {
       var newWait = 240000;
       if (!webProtocolError)
       {
           if (currentWait < 16000)
               newWait = currentWait + 250;
       }
       if (currentWait < 10000)
       {
           newWait = 10000;
       }
       if (currentWait < 240000 && currentWait >=10000)
       {
           newWait = currentWait * 2;
       }

       return newWait;
   }
   ```